# Vue Js & Firebase relational query problem

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating a project with Vue Js and Firebase. Facing some problem while querying relational data from Two tables. I already have idea about SQL database relation system. But as Firebase is a NoSQL database thats why can't figure out how to solve it.

**Table 1**
Customers 
  -> id 
  -> name

**Table 2**
Sales
  -> id
  -> customer_name
  -> date

Here is the query I do on my .vue files

```
  let ref = db.collection('sales').where("created_month", "==", moment().format('MM-YYYY'))
                                  .orderBy('timestamp', 'desc')

  ref.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
    snapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
      if(change.type == 'added'){
        let doc = change.doc
        this.sales.push({
          id:doc.id,
          item_name:doc.data().item_name,
          price:doc.data().price,
          timestamp:moment(doc.data().timestamp).format('ll')
        })
      }
    })
  })
```

My question is how can I retrieve customer name by using customer ID from customer table and show on the sales table.

Comment: Do you have the customer id in your Sales document? It seems you already have the `customer_name`. Or do you actually store in this field the customer id?

Comment: I have customer ID in sales document. Now how can I retrieve customer name based on customer ID and show it on the sales

Comment: "How can I retrieve customer name based on customer ID and show it on the sales" -> Pls look at my answer: IMHO, it answers this question. You get the `customer_name` in each object that is pushed into the `sales` array. Then it is just a matter of displaying the `sales` array with, for example, a `v-for` (https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/#Conditionals-and-Loops)

Answer (score 2):

Since your data model is as follows

> ```
> Document in Collection "Customers"
>  -> id
>  -> name
>
> Document in Collection "Sales"
>  -> id
>  -> customer_name
>  -> date
> ```

I make the assumption that the customer id is actually stored in a Sale document in the `customer_name` field.

Therefore, you need, in the listener, to fetch the Customer document, using the [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#get) method. The following should do the trick.

```
  const ref = db.collection('sales').where("created_month", "==", moment().format('MM-YYYY')).orderBy('timestamp', 'desc')

  ref.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
    snapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
      if(change.type == 'added'){
        let doc = change.doc;

        const customerId = doc.data().customer_name;
        const customerDocRef = db.collection('customers').doc(customerId);

        customerDocRef.get()
        .then(doc => {
           const customer_name = doc.data().name;  // Here we get the value of customer_name

          this.sales.push({
            id:doc.id,
            item_name:doc.data().item_name,
            price:doc.data().price,
            timestamp:moment(doc.data().timestamp).format('ll'),
            customer_name: customer_name  //Here we add the customer_name in each object that is pushed into the sales array
          })
      }
    })
  })
```

---

Having said that, one classical approach in NoSQL databases is to denormalize your data in such a way your queries are easy and fast to execute.

In your case it would mean that when you save a new Sale, you directly write in the Sale document the `customer_id` AND the `customer_name`.

I would suggest that you have a look at this Firebase video where this approach is very well explained: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_hR4K4auoQ. You could also read this "famous" post about NoSQL data-modeling approaches: https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/

Comment: @ShakilZaman Hi, did you have time to look at the proposed solution?

Answer (score 1):

Can maybe just use filter() or find()?

```
let userSales = []
this.sales.forEach( sale => {
const costumer = costumers.find( costumer => costumer.id === sale.id)
userSales.push(costumer)
}
```

Or just put sales collection in user collection.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
  let ref = db.collection('customers').where("id", "==", id);
  ref.get()
    .then(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
            let customerName = doc.data().name;
            let salesRef     = db.collection('sales').doc('some-id');
            salesRef.set({
                   customerName : customerName,
                   date: "date",
                   id: "id"
                  }).then(function() {
                       console.log("Document successfully written!");
                  }).catch(function(error) {
                       console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
                  });
        });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    });
```

Add a reference to collection `customers` then using the query `where` you can retrieve the customer name. Then you can add that name to a `sales` document

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Here is my complete code: https://codeshare.io/29qBNK. Can you please suggest me what to do now.